# What does % mean in this statement in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am learning kotlin and in a snipped of code iterating through a list i have this line:
currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % myList.size

I am confused by the % sign.  Does it mean that you should increment currentIndex by 1 until you get to the size of myList?

I couldnt find anything in documentation about it and the text book just seems to assume I should know!

Comment: That is a common operator in many languages. While the semantics may differ, it's commonly used for as a "modulus" or "division remainder" operator. Any decent book or tutorial or class should have taught you that.

Comment: In C, the meaning of modulo is slightly ambiguous. In Java and Kotlin, it's just the remainder operator, so there's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Modulus operator. Take a look to the next links:

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html
- https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/operators

EDIT 1: Sorry, I forgot to answer your question really.

What it makes that statement is to increment the currentIndex by 1 at each iteration, until it ranges the whole list. When that happens, the currentIndex is initialized to 0 again. When currentIndex = 9, the next iteration will be set to zero again.

Cheers.

Comment: thanks, i get what the modulus operator does i just dont understand why i wouldnt just do currentIndex + 1, the size of my list is 10 so 1 modulo 10 is 1 2 modulo 10 is 2 and so on, wouldnt i acheive the same result by just doing currentIndex++

Comment: What would happen if `currentIndex` were 9?

Comment: @LearningToCode I have edited the answer because I missed really the question. Sorry!!

Comment: ah i see that makes much more sense, thank you :)